# How to assign a numerical value template Type

Tags: c#, templates, casting, type-conversion

I can not assign a numerical value.
Is supposed to use a template for double and int values.
The cast does not help.

In C + + had no problems.

```
    class array<Type>
    {
        public void alloc(int n)
        {
            a=new Type[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = (Type)0; <-----Error

        }
           Type[] a;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Is it a generic array?

Comment: C# is not C++. C# has *generics* which are completely different from C++ templates.

Comment: Although if you just want to initialize to 0, try `default(Type)`.

Comment: I want to write a template class.
With a specific logic.
On the basis of the array.

Comment: default() if 0, and if you need to assign 1?

Comment: @Mixer You can't. At least, not easily.